# Get my Facebook wall posts

Tags: facebook, hello.js

I'm using Hello.Js to get my Facebook wall posts. To doing so I have registered my demo app on developer.facebook.com (using a localhost url).

My hello.js setup is the following:

```
hello.init({
    facebook: '<mykey>'
},
{
    redirect_uri: 'redirect.html',
});
```

and this is the Facebook login:

```
var onFacebookError = function (e) {
    $facebookEl.text(e.error.message);
};

// Facebook instance
var facebook = hello('facebook');

// Login
facebook.login().then(function (r) {
    // Get Profile
    facebook.api('me').then(function (p) {
        $facebookEl.html('<span><img src="' + p.thumbnail + '" width=50 class="roundedAvatar" /><span style="margin-left: 15px;">Connected to Facebook as ' + p.name + '</span></span>');
    }, onFacebookError);
}, onFacebookError);
```

The OAUth connection is working fine, but when I try to get my wall post, using:

```
// Facebook instance
var facebook = hello('facebook');        

facebook.api('facebook:/me/share', function (r) {
    var posts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < r.data.length; i++) {
        var o = r.data[i];
        posts.push({ social: 'facebook', text: o.text });
    };
});
```

I get and empty r.data result.

What can the issue be? Do I have to enable other permissions on the Facebook app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the user's timeline posts, you need to query the [`/feed` edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed) with the `user_posts` permission.

I would recommend that you always try your calls in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) first. This way you can be sure if this is an issue with the API or your implementation.